# How to access data on Phidgets USB photo sensor

Tags: usb

I work for a university that has a video display sign (ucview) running Ubuntu as the OS. We have a [photo sensor USB](https://www.phidgets.com/?tier=3&catid=2&pcid=1&prodid=4) attached to (hopefully) pull relevant brightness data from the that sensor for use with a python script that will call out to the USB sensor to gather adjust the brightness of the signage. The sensor uses Phidgets drivers.

I do not know exact how to query that data.

Comment: Can you provide a link or product name for the sensor you have?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  The sensor is [link] (https://www.phidgets.com/?tier=3&catid=2&pcid=1&prodid=4)

Answer (score 0):

The phidget has an API available over python. You can install it with instructions [here](https://www.phidgets.com/docs/Language_-_Python_Linux_Terminal). Once you've done that, you can use the API, which is described lower on the product page for the specific sensor. If you're having difficulty, you can take a look at the [examples](https://www.phidgets.com/?view=code_samples&lang=Python).

Comment: I made use of the API and the Python script example for LightSensor.  I am getting errors a plenty.  I ensured that I had the library for phidget22 installed.

Comment: If you installed the library correctly, it is likely a question for stackoverflow.